# How to remove all non-word characters in except white spaces and periods in acronyms using python regex

Tags: python, regex-lookarounds

```
test_str = "a.. x what! he was a in the U.S.A.F but in the accounts dept?"
```

We need to remove all non-words except for the single white spaces that already separate the words and the periods that are in acronyms .

Result should look like: `a x What he was in the U.S.A.F but in the accounts dept`.

I tried: Using 9 as replacement for visibility

```
re_result = re.sub(pattern = r"(?<=\W)[\W][\S](?=\W)", repl= '9', string=test_str, count=0, flags=0)
```

I get:
`a..9 what! he was a in the U.S.A.F but in the accounts dept?`

1. Why is the x being recognized as non-word OR non-space,how to make it look for non-word and non-space.
2. How to remove the punctuations at the word boundaries , adding `r"(?<=\W)[\W][\S](?=\W)|\b\W\b"` doesnt work.

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: `x` isn't whitespace, therefore it matches `\S`.

Comment: non-word and non-space: `[^\w\s]`

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I believe you need to do

```py
re.sub(pattern = r"\W{2,}|\W$", repl= ' ', string=test_str).strip()
```

This will replace any non-word character sequence more than 1 symbol in length by space. Also it will replace last symbol if it's not word symbol.

Demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/BPubSn/1)

Answer (score 0):

Using `\S` matches a non whitespace character, so it will also match the `x` char.

Looking at the example data, you might use:

```
\W+(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `\W+` Match 1 or more times a non word character
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2AeWeL/1)

Comment: Thank You @The fourth bird. While, this should work for all practical cases can you help me in understanding 2 points : (1) I'm assuming we can use (?=\s) to avoid double negative for readability's sake. (2) This fails is there is a nonword at the beginning of a word or total string so i tried r"\W+(?=\s)|(?<=\s)\W+|^\W+" and seems to work , do you see any problems with this or a better way probably to write this.

Comment: @Kris Using `(?=\s)` is not the same as `(?!\S)` as the former needs a whitespace char to be present. Perhaps try it like this `\W+(?!\S)|(?<!\S)\W+` https://regex101.com/r/aX4zKu/1